# how to get the number of shared and unshared True and false across all rows

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df<- structure(list(rowid = 1:12, P = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE), T = c(TRUE, TRUE, 
TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE), 
    X = c(TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, TRUE, 
    FALSE, TRUE, TRUE)), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))
```

I am trying to get the when all rows are True, or False or mixed.

So in this case, it would be like this

```
AllTure  AllFalse  Mixed 
9          0        2
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

With `dplyr`, you can do:

```
df %>%
 summarise(AllTure = sum(rowSums(.[2:4]) == 3),
           AllFalse = sum(rowSums(.[2:4]) == 0),
           Mixed = n() - (AllFalse + AllTure))

  AllTure AllFalse Mixed
    <int>    <int> <int>
1       9        0     3
```

Comment: I liked it already and accept as soon as It allows me . Thanks again

Answer (score 5):

An option would be

```
table(rowSums(df[-1]))
```

---

Inorder to get the expected labels, we can convert it to a `factor` with `levels` specified

```
s1 <- rowSums(df[-1])
table(factor(replace(s1, !s1  %in% c(0, 3), 1), levels = c(0, 1, 3), 
      labels = c("AllFalse", "Mixed", "AllTrue")))
# AllFalse    Mixed  AllTrue 
#      0        3        9
```

NOTE: Both solutions are only using `base R`

---

If we need it in `tidyverse`, an option without reshaping nor doing the same computation multiple times, get the sum of the rows with `reduce`, then convert the 'Sum' column to `factor` with `levels` specified and get the frequency with `count`

```
library(tidyverse)    
df %>%
   transmute(Sum = reduce(.[-1], `+`)) %>% 
   mutate(Sum = factor(recode(Sum, `3` = 'AllTrue', `0`= 'AllFalse', 
       .default = 'Mixed'),
   levels = c("AllTrue", 'AllFalse', 'Mixed'))) %>% 
   count(Sum, .drop = FALSE)
# A tibble: 3 x 2
#  Sum          n
#  <fct>    <int>
#1 AllTrue      9
#2 AllFalse     0
#3 Mixed        3
```

Comment: I liked your answer but I will accept the one below because of the way he or she presented it. Thanks

Comment: @Learner If you need it in `dplyr` format, it can be done

Answer (score 3):

Another option with `cut` is to create `breaks` at proper intervals and assign `labels` accordingly.

```
table(cut(rowSums(df[-1]), breaks = c(-Inf,0, ncol(df) - 2, Inf),
      labels = c("AllFalse", "Mixed", "AllTrue")))

#AllFalse    Mixed  AllTrue 
#       0        3        9
```

Ideally the `break` value should be `ncol(df) - 1`, we use `ncol(df) - 2` here because we want to ignore the first column from calculation.

Answer (score 2):

In general, I think the `rowSums` solutions are better. But I often like reshaping to long data in order to make operations more flexible, e.g. not hard-coding which columns to sum. I'd also throw out there that you might want to keep the number of columns you're matching against (in this case, 3) in a variable, again to avoid hard-coding. The trade-off for flexibility is that this is a little redundant, with 2 calls to `summarise` functions.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

n <- ncol(df) - 1
df %>%
  gather(key, value, -rowid) %>%
  group_by(rowid) %>%
  summarise(all_true = sum(sum(value) == n),
            all_false = sum(sum(value) == 0),
            mixed = sum(!sum(value) %in% c(0, n))) %>%
  summarise_at(vars(-rowid), sum)
#> # A tibble: 1 x 3
#>   all_true all_false mixed
#>      <int>     <int> <int>
#> 1        9         0     3
```